# Convert Date to javascript format

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, date, isodate

I am trying to convert this date into **Mon Nov 26 2018 10:32:04 GMT** (I am getting this data from the Api so i can't make changes to it)

I assume it is considering  26 as months thats why it is showing it as invalid date

Can Anyone help me with this. How to convert that date into the expected output i specified.

How to get

```
 var d = new Date("26-11-2018 10:32:04")
    return d; //Error: Invalid Date

expected Output: Mon Nov 26 2018 10:32:04 (IST)
```

Comment: `Date("26-11-2018 10:32:04")` ?

Comment: some time ago I have to use this library to parse dates with custom format : https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs ; it's pretty lightweight and easy to use

Comment: @CodeManiac what's this ?

Comment: @CodeManiac This is the actual data "2018-11-26T09:02:04.000+0000" but while mapping it is returning as"26-11-2018 10:32:04"

Comment: @Manmeetsahni : your initial string does not contain information about the time zone. Is your output always GMT?

Comment: @HereticMonkey i have tried some of those solutions but doesn't seem to work

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov No its not. I want it accordin to IST

Comment: "Some of the solutions" won't necessarily answer your question. The question is exactly the same. I assure you, at least one of the answers will work. For instance, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38593735/215552).

Answer (score 1):

Use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) to parse the date.

```
moment("26-11-2018 10:32:04", "DD-MM-YYYY HH-mm-ss").toDate()
```

Alternatively, if you really don't want to use moment for whatever reason, you can use regex magic.

```
new Date("26-11-2018 10:32:04".replace(/^(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+) (\d+):(\d+):(\d+)$/, "$3-$2-$1T$4:$5:$6Z"))
```

Comment: Is there any other way that i can do this without using moment js

Comment: I've edited my answer to include an alternative solution.

Comment: In the moment example, the hours token should probably be HH not hh. The second "solution" changes the timestamp from local to UTC.

Comment: @RobG He said he's getting his data from an API so I'd hope it's not a local time.

Answer (score -1):

This is not a robust as @Yevgen answer but it also much simpler.

All I'm doing is removing the - and flipping the day and month values

```
const items = "26-11-2018 10:32:04".split('-')
new Date(`${items[1]} ${items[0]} ${items[2]}`)
```

This works for personal projects but I highly recommend using moment.js

Comment: This returns an invalid date.

Comment: Works in chrome. What env are you using?